# 404 response even though I can see data on page

Tags: php, wordpress

We are building a college search site on top of wordpress and have our own custom pages.[image]
After the search results, when user clicks on college link, it opens a page
http://studyn.us/c-102614-university-of-alaska-fairbanks
Not sure why the network status is 404 even though I can see the data on the page.

I have attached the response from network status in chrome. You can see that we have data in the page as well.

Based on url, we redirect to another template. Below the code written in functions.php

```
function redirect_to_college_template()
{
if( !is_front_page()) :
$url =  "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$url = trim($url, '/');
$headURL =  substr($url, strrpos($url, '/')+1);
 $college=explode ("-",$headURL);
  $var=$college[0];
$college=$college[1];
endif;
echo $college;
if($var=='c' & is_numeric($college)!='')
    {
    //echo $college;
        include( get_template_directory() . '/college-page.php' );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_college_template' );
```

I am not sure why are we getting 404 even though the data is displayed. When google crawls the website, it is the same problem. 
Is it because the way code is written in functions.php ?

Could this problem be because title of the page does not match the url ?

Comment: a 404 is just a status code, and the server can send out anything it wants as the content. What's happening is basically the equivalent of a jedi mind trick: "This is not the page you are you looking for", even though it really is.

Comment: This happened for me when updating Apache. I believe the newer versions of Wordpress has it covered. - As far as I know, it's because of the rewrites, and apache checking for the actual file - Which isn't there - Thus defaulting to 404 as status message.

Comment: But google is not able to index the pages. All these urls  http://studyn.us/c-102614-university-of-alaska-fairbanks are also part of sitemap.xml . google crawls the  url and is unable to find the contents. There has to be a way out.

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you using?

Comment: I have no idea what `http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that WordPress still continues to look for a page/post that matches the URL. While you are handling it....you have to tell WP to stop looking elsewhere.

```
global $wp_query;
if($wp_query->is_404){
    $wp_query->is_404=false;
    $wp_query->is_archive=true;
}
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
```

You will probably want this inside your second IF statement.

Comment: The solution works. Would like to clarify if this is the the right way to solve the problem or we are forcing a 200 response code on the page.

Comment: Alternatively, you can look into registering a wordpress route. Take a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes

Comment: Yes looks like a better option.